# Assign a variable inside an $.ajax() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I would like to assign a variable inside an $.ajax() function so that it's still available the next time the function is called...

Is this possible?

`var xxx = 1;` isn't doing the job.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should do something like that and *avoid* DOM manipulation for that...

```
(function($){
    var YourApp = {
        var your_vault : "",

        binders : function(){
            $('#button').on('click',YourApp.ajaxRequest);
        },
        ajaxRequest : function() {
            // Do something with YourApp.your_vault     
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://someurl.com',
                succes: function(){
                    // Modifying your value:
                    YourApp.your_vault = 'A wonderfull new value';
                }
            });
        }
    };
    YourApp.binders();
})(jQuery);
```

Since I don't have real code from your app I can't give more exact code but I think you'll get the idea.

The key idea is the scope. Whenever you have your var in a higher scope you'll be able to modify it in a lower scope, **without** using the `var` keyword.

Answer (score 2):

The variable must be stored in a static place e.g. hidden input or in a data-attribute.

```
$('#hiddenId').val(1);
// Or
$('#someFooId').data('last-ajax-value', 1);
```

Next time you call the function, use this to get the previous value:

```
var lastValue = $('#hiddenId').val();
// Or
var lastValue = $('#someFooId').data('last-ajax-value');
```

[`data` docs:](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

> Description: Store arbitrary data associated with the matched elements

Comment: I think it's not *must*. Your solution is the quicker but not the best. If he has all setted inside an object, he can changes the property of the object and be reused later.

Comment: @AntonioLaguna. Might be true, **It's very hard to tell what is the best way for him with the missing context of his question** :(

Comment: Very contrived solution. He can store his data in any variable in a higher scope, without recoursing to attaching it to DOM elements.

Comment: @gdoron Thanks for your answer. This actually achieves a good result for me, but I will go ahead and give Antonio the tick because his solution is more suited to my problem. Sorry I didn't provide more information for you!

Answer (score 1):

If your variable is defined at a global level, then it can be used at many places.

You need to learn about [variable scoping](http://javascript.about.com/library/bltut07.htm), and this same applies to javascript, in whichever function its run.